# Scrolling to Item

Tags: android, scroll, items, sorting

I'm new to Android and I want to know how to scroll down to a position specified by a button in `ListView`. Say for example I have an array of 5000 items, sorted. I will have 33 letters on top of the screen and user wants to get to position that starts with letter 'M'. How can I make it so that user can get to that position without using fingers to scroll.

I know it is possible in HTML (`<li>`/`<ul>` tags) but I would like to know how this can be done in Android `ListView`.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition(int)

Answer (score 1):

Do it by using the method [`smoothScrollToPosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29)

You only have to know the index, but that would be no problem in a sorted list.